# Abe first time execution

Tags: abe

I'm running Abe to generate a Blockchain clone. It's been generating the database for over 3 days. The server is not very powerful, but 3 days seems too much time. The last tx output:

block_tx 121881 469801
block_tx 121881 469802
block_tx 121881 469803
block_tx 121881 469804
block_tx 121881 469805
block_tx 121881 469806
block_tx 121881 469807
block_tx 121881 469808
block_tx 121881 469809
commit
block_tx 121882 469810
block_tx 121882 469811
block_tx 121882 469812
block_tx 121882 469813
block_tx 121882 469814
block_tx 121882 469815
block_tx 121882 469816
block_tx 121882 469817
block_tx 121882 469818
block_tx 121882 469819
block_tx 121882 469820
commit
block_tx 121883 469821
block_tx 121883 469822
block_tx 121883 469823
block_tx 121883 469824
block_tx 121883 469825
block_tx 121883 469826
block_tx 121883 469827
block_tx 121883 469828
block_tx 121883 469829
block_tx 121883 469830
block_tx 121883 469831
block_tx 121883 469832
block_tx 121883 469833
block_tx 121883 469834
block_tx 121883 469835
block_tx 121883 469836
block_tx 121883 469837
block_tx 121883 469838
block_tx 121883 469839
commit

Is this correct? How much more time will I need to wait?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The initial block file parsing can take a lot of time. From the [readme](https://github.com/jtobey/bitcoin-abe#slow-startup):

> Reading the block files takes much too long, several days or more for the main BTC block chain as of 2013. However, if you use a persistent database, Abe remembers where it stopped reading and starts more quickly the second time.

It depends on the hardware you have, besides a good CPU it probably benefits from a fast hard drive (SSD at best).
On my Macbook Air (2013, 8GB RAM, i7, SSD) it took a few days.